# Angular 8 i18n Persistent target tag in xlf file

Tags: angular, internationalization, angular-i18n

Every time I add new text that will required translation then I run :

`ng xi18n --output-path src/locale --out-file dutch.xlf --i18n-locale nl`

I get `ERROR in xliff parse errors:`  `misses a translation`

So what happened is that I've added all the `<target>` tags with translation but it get removed even with `@@customId` `<target>` tags simple gone!

Any ideas!

Thanks.